# Android - BufferedReader stuck in infinite loop while reading CSV file

Tags: android, csv, android-asynctask, bufferedreader

I have the following code to read a CSV file in Android:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFile), getResources().getString(R.string.charset)));

List<String> readLines = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

for (String readLine = br.readLine(); readLine != null ; br.readLine()) {
    if (readLine.contains("------------")) {
        break;
    } else {
        readLines.add(readLine);
    }
}

br.close();
```

The problem is that my loop runs infinitely.  This loop is located inside an `AsyncTask`, which I wonder could be the cause of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to assign `readLine` each time through the loop:

```
for (String readLine = br.readLine(); readLine != null ; readLine = br.readLine()) {
```

Or a bit more compactly:

```
String readLine;
while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
```